# Нужно поднять элемент без участия сетки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Хочу поднять элементы  *button* в Bootstrap v4, но просто понятия не имею, как это сделать, по идеи сами кнопки заключены уже в *div*. Они просто ускакали вниз..

Новичок, так что простите за глупый вопрос. Ответ, как это сделать не нашел в документации, ткните носом, если можете!

Спасибо за помощь!

```html
  <div class="container text-center" style="padding: 10px "></div>  
             <span>
        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white text-center" style="padding: 20px" > Аналитическая справка </div>
             </span>    
        <div class="text-center" style="padding: 20px">
            <span class="py-2 px-3 bg-info text-white rounded mybtn text-center">
                Отделение дополнительного образования детей «Источник» функционирует с января 2009 года и является структурным подразделением ГБОУ СОШ №538.
            </span>
            <div class="shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                <img src="/Storage/imgs/81347ccbfe62480a9dd72dde726d3076.jpg" alt="#" width="250px" height="250px" class="rounded float-left img-thumbnail shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Основные задачи структурного подразделения ОДОд:</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Обеспечение гарантий прав ребенка на дополнительное образование по различным направлениям работы ОДОд;</button>
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Творческое развитие личности и реализация с этой целью программ дополнительного <br>образования в интересах личности ребенка, общества, государства;</button>
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Развитие мотивации к познанию и творчеству;</button>
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Организация учебно – исследовательской деятельности;</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

[image: Пример того, что имею]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно завернуть изображение в один блок,например, с классом "col-sm-4",а текст и кнопки в другой блок, с классом "col-sm-8".[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ох, интересное решение, достаточно симпатично выглядит, спасибо за помощь!